# Example of unique 3sat solution

Tags: sat, satisfiability

I am searching for 3sat problems having unique solution. Till now, I only found one site [https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hoos/SATLIB/benchm.html](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Ehoos/SATLIB/benchm.html)

There are good examples of 3sat instance on that site but the problem is they have more than 1 solution if it's satisfiable. I want such big instances of 3sat of having 20 40 variables and at least 100 clauses
( More will be good ) ***but having unique solution.*** Where can I get such list of questions Or is there any algorithm which can generate 3sat question having unique solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct a 3SAT problem with unique solution, you could use an arithmetic circuit like an [adder](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-implement-half-adder/) or a [multiplier](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-multiplier-in-digital-logic/). The resulting output lines are then compared against the known result using a [digital comparator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/magnitude-comparator-in-digital-logic/).

The design flow could be as follows:

1. Write the arithmetic expression to be used.
   Examples: x * 7, x - 1, x * x
2. Translate the expression into a boolean circuit of logical gates.
   This can be done by a suitable python script.
3. Transform the circuit into [Conjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (CNF)
   using a tool like [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/).
4. If the resulting number of clauses is too big or too small,
   go back to step 1. and adjust the bitlength of the expression operand.

The simplest variant of such a circuit would be a digital comparator without pre-attached arithmetic circuit.

To get a unique solution, the arithmetic expression must have a unique solution. Counterexamples include integer division and integer sqare root.

Answer (score 0):

https://it-in-industry.com/itii_papers/2019/7219itii03.pdf discusses generating unique 3-sat problems. Might be a good place to start.